# How to detect a close event for a materialize select dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, materialize

I'm trying to implement label functionality for select as for text input: when select is opened, the label goes smaller, and when select is closed, if no value is selected, returns to initial position.

I was able to put two divs, one for regular input label and other for the select dropdown.

The select dropdown will be hidden initially and only the input label will be visible. On clicking the input label, I am hiding the label and then showing the select dropdown and triggering the drop down open event so that the drop down opens automatically. Now the issue is if nothing is selected from the drop down and if I close the drop down, I want to hide the select drop down and show the input label.

I have tried onClose() onChange() and nothing seems to work.

onChange() can only detect if I select an option from the dropdown. But it doesn't detect close if nothing is selected.

Answer (score 0):

At last I was able to figure that focusout() works in this case.
on focus out just hide the select drop down label and show the input label, if the input value is null.